# I'm not sure backing-up my mysql-db worked

Tags: mysql, backup

I ran (on ubuntu):

```
mysqldump -u.. -p.. --all-databases > ...
```

When I check the size of the backup file its ~600k, however, when checking the `ibdata1` file, its size is ~10MB. As you can see, I'm no expert in mysql. If I'm not wrong, there is redundancy in the ibdata file so this check isn't very meaningful. Is there a better check I can perform that doesn't involve creating a new db from the backup?

Answer (score 1):

Restoring db from the backup and comparing (at least) row counts in tables would be the best check.

Ideally you want to check data as well.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I've been uncertain of the size/integrity of a dump there's only one thing I do.  I rebuild my database(s) from the dump with new database names (obviously to not wipe out your db).  Then I run varying levels of CHECK TABLE, do row counts, retrieve known records etc.  This way you can satisfy yourself the dump is good.

Answer (score 1):

the backup file from mysqldump is simply SQL statement, you can actually read the file and check whether it covers all your tables or not. i use this method a lot and seems ok to me